# React - Queue rendering of children on completion of CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, es6-promise

What are some other methods to implement a component in react
that queues multiple sequentially 'loading' bars (css transition) if a button is clicked.

On clicks bar N starts animating only when loading bar N-1 is done animating (so only once the prev is done)

Quick Implementation -> https://codesandbox.io/s/yjp8pznrqj

Comment: Not sure about the exact implementation, but how about async/await from es7? You could setup an async function that does its thing, then runs again with a different argument (or runs a different function), etc...

Comment: I'm using it to make 2 different ajax calls like this:

const createSessionInfo = async function() {
  try {
    let siteInfo = await fetchSessionInfo('site.list');
    let userInfo = await fetchSessionInfo('user.info');
    // parse siteInfo and userInfo
  } catch(err) {
    // do something with err
  }
}

const fetchSessionInfo = function(url) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  n.call(url, {}, function (err, res) {
   if (err) {
    reject(err);
   } else {
    resolve(res);
   }
  })
 })
}